How to verify that all elements of a list comply with some conditions
I have this input payload to a Mule 4 application:
{
  "P_CUST_ACCOUNTS": [
    {
      "ACCOUNT_NUMBER": 62972,
      "ADDR_CHG_FLAG": "N"
    },
    {
      "ACCOUNT_NUMBER": 94561,
      "ADDR_CHG_FLAG": null
    }
  ]
}

I need to ensure the following conditions.

check that each object in the array contains ACCOUNT_NUMBER and ADDR_CHG_FLAG
check that each array object's ACCOUNT_NUMBER value is not null and is not an empty
check that each array object's ADDR_CHG_FLAG value is not null and is not an empty string

and would like to simply return a true or false based on if all the above conditions are met.
So in the above case, I would get a boolean value of true.
So far, I have been able to get the first condition working with ...
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
---
{
  acctnbr: payload.P_CUST_ACCOUNTS every ($.ACCOUNT_NUMBER?),
  addrchgflag: payload.P_CUST_ACCOUNTS every ($.ADDR_CHG_FLAG?)
}

but needed to separate each field (like above), as putting them together (like below) to get a single boolean value returned doesn't return the correct value
if ((payload.P_CUST_ACCOUNTS every ($.ACCOUNT_NUMBER?) == false)
     or (payload.P_CUST_ACCOUNTS every ($.ADDR_CHG_FLAG?) == false)
   ) false
else true

Wondering if there is a way using DataWeave to correctly get a single boolean value based on if all of the conditions above are met.

Do you mean that ACCOUNT_NUMBER is not null and is a number? Because it is not a string in the example.

Please [edit] your title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is just a repeat of the tag (which should not be in the title at all), plus the useless word "issue", which says nothing. That leaves "2.0", which has no meaning either. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user skimming a list of search results will know what it contains. For suggestions on writing a good title, see [ask].

I edited the question for you this time. Next time please follow the recommendation from Ken White.

"So in the above case, I would get a boolean value of true." That is incorrect because in the input there is an instance of "ADDR_CHG_FLAG": null so the result is false.

@KenWhite - thanks for editing the title. I was waiting to edit it to something similar, but each time i have tried so far, I got an error ... 'There are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow. Please try again later.' ... so I just hadn't been able to yet.

I edited the message, not Ken.

Ok thanks @aled. I assumed, as the title was updated before the comment. I was attempting to edit it but was getting the error mentioned above. I will keep in mind moving forward to have a more specific/userful title/description.

You got the main part right, using the every() function to check that all members of an array comply with a condition. Also using the key present ? selector for the first condition.
What is missing is to put all the conditions together. You just need to decide how to express each condition in DataWeave and then since each element needs to comply with all of them just connect with the and operator.
For clarity I put the full expression of the condition in a new function.
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
fun check(x)=
    x.ACCOUNT_NUMBER? 
    and x.ADDR_CHG_FLAG?
    and isInteger(x.ACCOUNT_NUMBER)
    and (x.ADDR_CHG_FLAG is String)
    and !isEmpty(x.ADDR_CHG_FLAG)
---
payload.P_CUST_ACCOUNTS every ((item) -> check(item))

I'm assuming that the right condition for ACCOUNT_NUMBER is to check if it is an integer number. If that assumption is not correct you can change it to be is String as for ADDR_CHG_FLAG.
The output for your input payload is false because the last ADDR_CHG_FLAG is null, so it doesn't satisfy the is String condition.
Note that in general you should not compare a boolean expression to true or false, because it already returns one of those values and make the expression more verbose without adding value. If needed use the not operator ! to negate the condition.
Now just as an alternative if you are interested in a more flexible or dynamic implementation, we could put the conditions in a list of lambdas. Then we check that for every item every condition in the list is true:
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays
output application/json  

var checks = [
  (x) -> x.ACCOUNT_NUMBER?,
  (x) -> x.ADDR_CHG_FLAG?,
  (x) -> isInteger(x.ACCOUNT_NUMBER),
  (x) -> x.ADDR_CHG_FLAG is String,
  (x) -> !isEmpty(x.ADDR_CHG_FLAG)
]

fun check(a: Array, checks: Array)=
    a every (
        (item) -> checks every (
            (check) -> check(item)
        )
    )
---
check(payload.P_CUST_ACCOUNTS, checks)

This solution could be expanded to activate/deactivate some checks.

I tweaked just a bit to finish it off (below), but basically, what you provided did the trick. Thanks a bunch!
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
fun check(x)=
    x.ACCOUNT_NUMBER? 
    and x.ADDR_CHG_FLAG?
    and !isEmpty(trim(x.ACCOUNT_NUMBER))
    and (x.ACCOUNT_NUMBER is String)
    and sizeOf(x.ACCOUNT_NUMBER) == 5
    and (x.ADDR_CHG_FLAG is String)
    and !isEmpty(trim(x.ADDR_CHG_FLAG))
    and sizeOf(x.ADDR_CHG_FLAG) == 1
---
payload.P_CUST_ACCOUNTS every ((item) -> check(item))


You can adapt the solution to your particular needs of course. But please don't add code in comments, it is unreadable.

I added a more dynamic solution as an alternative.
